# Need help finding a song

Tags: song-poetry, music

years ago I visited Majdanek, one of the most intact concentration camps. The tour ends in a huge heap of ashes. There I was, standing in front of those ashes, thinking about the meaning of life, after seeing all those gas chambers and crematoriums. I was feeling very sad. Then a small group of young haredim arrived at the other side of the heap. After a while, they started singing a very beautiful song. I didn't knew the song, nor could i understand one word of what they were singing. You see, i'm not a very emotional person, but when those guys started singing that song in front of those ashes I started crying like a baby.

Until today when i remember that moment it gives me chills. It's one of my top 5 memories for sure. It would mean a lot to me to know what song they were singing, and if possible, the translated lyrics.

Here's all I was able to record while crying [audio only]: https://youtu.be/QDH-wQ02OR0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is 'Yizkrem'. Here is a link to one performance of this song, but there are probably many others online: https://youtu.be/9Y89PGlabBE  The part of the song that you recorded can be first heard at around 49 seconds in.

The lyrics [loosely translated by me]: Merciful Father, Who dwells on high, remember with mercy the holy individuals and communities that gave their lives in sanctification of Your Name. (this next part is what you recorded:) Remember them, remember them for good. Remember them, remember them together with the rest of the righteous throughout history.

It can be found in every siddur/prayer book, for it is said almost every shabbos near the end of the morning prayer.

Comment: That's it, thank you! It's even more powerful now that i know what they were singing. It's a very beautiful song!

Comment: @Jonhz - You're welcome. Thank YOU. You made my day by giving me the opportunity to help you in such a meaningful way.